# Android: Activity Window Died (WINDOW DIED) on 4.0.4 ICS Devices

Tags: android, android-activity, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am getting IllegalArgumentException in an 4.0 ICS Devices on one of my Activity..

I/WindowManager(  529): WINDOW DIED Window{419a4a18 XXX.XXXXXX.XXX.XXX/XXX.XXXXXX.XXX.XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX paused=false}

```
E/SurfaceTexture(  225): [com.sample/com.sample.MyActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!

E/SurfaceTextureClient( 9044): dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044): IllegalArgumentException locking surface
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:76)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2157)
    E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1846)
    E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2658)
    E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
   E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
    E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

New Logs : 16 -08 -2012

Device Used : Samsung Galaxy S3

Android Version : 4.0.4

Issue not seen in 2.3 and below..

I have a TabActivity, within which i have childactivites(List Activities)..From one of my child activity i go to one more activity and do some work and come back to same Child activity(Update the View in ListActivity).If I Repeatedly do the  above i get the Below Exception and screen goes Blank.

```
08-16 15:43:00.271: I/ClipboardServiceEx(533): Send intent for dismiss clipboard dialog inside hideCurrentInputLocked() !
08-16 15:43:00.291: D/memalloc(224): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x45808000 size:3768320 fd:56
08-16 15:43:00.291: D/memalloc(27338): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x60a28000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:93
08-16 15:43:00.291: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(224): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
08-16 15:43:00.291: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(224): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
08-16 15:43:00.291: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.291: I/ActivityManager(533): Displayed shortComponentName: +329ms
08-16 15:43:00.291: D/DEFERED_APP_VISIBILITY(533): tweaking closing app
08-16 15:43:00.301: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.301: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.301: D/memalloc(27338): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x602f8000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:00.301: D/memalloc(27338): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ff38000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:00.301: W/InputDispatcher(533): channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-16 15:43:00.301: E/InputDispatcher(533): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-16 15:43:00.301: W/InputDispatcher(533): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel
08-16 15:43:00.301: I/WindowManager(533): WINDOW DIED Window{427c45a0 XXX.XXXXXX.XX/XXX.XXXXXX.XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX paused=false}
08-16 15:43:00.311: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.311: D/memalloc(224): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x43117000 size:3768320 fd:62
08-16 15:43:00.311: D/memalloc(224): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x43117000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:00.311: D/memalloc(224): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x434af000 size:3768320 fd:43
08-16 15:43:00.311: D/memalloc(224): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x434af000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:00.311: D/memalloc(27338): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5f66f000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:00.311: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.311: E/InputQueue-JNI(27338): channel '427c45a0 com.org.ui/com.org.ui.CreateContactActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-16 15:43:00.321: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.321: D/memalloc(224): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x43117000 size:3768320 fd:40
08-16 15:43:00.331: D/memalloc(27338): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5f66f000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:61
08-16 15:43:00.341: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(224): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
08-16 15:43:00.341: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(224): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
08-16 15:43:00.341: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.361: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.371: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.391: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.401: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.421: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.441: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.451: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.471: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.491: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.501: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.521: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.521: W/SurfaceFlinger(224): id=1810 Removed idx=5 Map Size=5
08-16 15:43:00.521: W/SurfaceFlinger(224): id=1809 Removed idx=3 Map Size=4
08-16 15:43:00.521: W/SurfaceFlinger(224): id=1809 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=4
08-16 15:43:00.521: W/SurfaceFlinger(224): id=1807 Removed idx=1 Map Size=3
08-16 15:43:00.521: W/SurfaceFlinger(224): id=1807 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=3
08-16 15:43:00.521: D/KeyguardViewMediator(533): setHidden false
08-16 15:43:00.551: D/memalloc(224): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x453ad000 size:3768320 fd:32
08-16 15:43:00.551: D/memalloc(224): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x453ad000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:00.551: D/memalloc(224): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x43117000 size:3768320 fd:40
08-16 15:43:00.551: D/memalloc(224): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x43117000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:00.571: D/memalloc(224): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x4414e000 size:1146880 fd:68
08-16 15:43:00.571: D/memalloc(224): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4414e000 size:1146880
08-16 15:43:00.571: D/memalloc(224): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x42a2c000 size:3768320 fd:34
08-16 15:43:00.571: D/memalloc(224): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x42a2c000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:00.691: E/MP-Decision(1408): DOWN Ld:34 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:0.000000 seq:196.000000
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(533): getGsmLevel=5
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(533): getLevel=5 (SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte 5)
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(658): getGsmLevel=5
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(658): getLevel=5 (SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte 5)
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(658): getGsmLevel=5
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(658): getLevel=5 (SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte 5)
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(533): getDbm 1
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(533): getGsmDbm=-77
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(533): getDbm=-77
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(533): getAsuLevel 1
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(533): getGsmAsuLevel=18
08-16 15:43:00.701: W/SignalStrength(533): getAsuLevel=18
08-16 15:43:00.701: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(658): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte 5 level=5
08-16 15:43:00.932: I/power(533): *** release_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1 
08-16 15:43:00.932: D/PowerManagerService(533): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
08-16 15:43:00.932: W/ActivityManager(533): mDVFSLock.release()
08-16 15:43:01.312: E/SurfaceTexture(224): [com.org.ui/com.org.ui.CreateContactActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
08-16 15:43:01.312: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(27338): <SwapBuffers:763>: dequeue native buffer fail: No such device
08-16 15:43:01.312: E/SurfaceTexture(224): [com.org.ui/com.org.ui.CreateContactActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
08-16 15:43:01.312: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(27338): <GetSurfaceSize:276>: dequeue native buffer failed: No such device.
08-16 15:43:01.312: E/SurfaceTexture(224): [com.org.ui/com.org.ui.CreateContactActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
08-16 15:43:01.312: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(27338): <GetSurfaceSize:276>: dequeue native buffer failed: No such device.
08-16 15:43:01.312: E/Adreno200-EGL(27338): <eglSurfaceResize:4030>: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
08-16 15:43:01.312: W/HardwareRenderer(27338): EGL error: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
08-16 15:43:01.312: E/SurfaceTexture(224): [com.org.ui/com.org.ui.CreateContactActivity] queueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
08-16 15:43:01.312: E/SurfaceTextureClient(27338): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
08-16 15:43:01.312: D/memalloc(27338): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x60690000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:01.312: D/memalloc(27338): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x60a28000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:01.312: D/memalloc(27338): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5f66f000 size:3768320
08-16 15:43:01.312: W/HardwareRenderer(27338): Mountain View, we've had a problem here. Switching back to software rendering.
08-16 15:43:01.312: E/SurfaceTexture(224): [com.org.ui/com.org.ui.CreateContactActivity] connect: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338): IllegalArgumentException locking surface
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:76)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2157)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1846)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2658)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
08-16 15:43:01.322: E/ViewRootImpl(27338):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Activity is been killed by system "WINDOW DIED".???What is the reason behind IllegalArgumentException ..

17 - 08- 2012

Adding ANR Traces

```
    ----- pid 23522 at 2012-08-17 15:11:59 -----
    Cmd line: com.org.ui

    DALVIK THREADS:
    (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c3ccd0 self=0x18d7c30
    | sysTid=23522 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074070920
    | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5508 stm=1030 core=0
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:118)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:118)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=18 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x428acb78 self=0x1f78210
  | sysTid=27231 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=32950048
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x428accc0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=18 (pool-1-thread-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=17 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x422a2f08 self=0x1df2260
  | sysTid=25366 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=31652384
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=3 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=16 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4229a048 self=0x1d22328
  | sysTid=23628 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=30355128
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=50 stm=18 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4229a1a0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=16 (AsyncTask #5)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4239ff38 self=0x1cf18e8
  | sysTid=23620 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=30297720
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=13 stm=6 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x423a0058> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=12 (AsyncTask #4)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42383350 self=0x1ce8e60
  | sysTid=23619 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=30362952
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=12 stm=5 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x42383470> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=15 (AsyncTask #3)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419fc028 self=0x1c75928
  | sysTid=23606 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=27987104
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=13 stm=6 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x419fc148> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=14 (AsyncTask #2)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42333a08 self=0x1c8c400
  | sysTid=23562 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=29698528
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=10 stm=5 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x42333c80> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=13 (AsyncTask #1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Timer-0" prio=5 tid=11 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419df490 self=0x1abe1f0
  | sysTid=23538 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27981992
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x419df490> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:238)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b52c8 self=0x1a9bf00
  | sysTid=23534 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=28053104
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=6 stm=3 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b51c8 self=0x1aaff90
  | sysTid=23533 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27190280
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=5 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b17a8 self=0x1a7ee40
  | sysTid=23531 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27983144
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40c444f8> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:213)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b1650 self=0x1abba90
  | sysTid=23530 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27190632
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=22 stm=5 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40c325d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b14e8 self=0x1aa9f10
  | sysTid=23529 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27190568
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40c324f8> 
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:128)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b13f8 self=0x1aadcc8
  | sysTid=23528 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27983024
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=73 stm=49 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b12b0 self=0x1a9dda0
  | sysTid=23527 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27766168
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b11b8 self=0x19c7f78
  | sysTid=23526 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27706080
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419b10d8 self=0x1982b48
  | sysTid=23524 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27705984
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=59 stm=6 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 23522 -----
```

What might be the reason for ActivityThread to get Blocked??
Thanks

NitZ

Comment: I think I got a similar error once, I think the problem was, that I had an AlertDialog open, and I called finish on the Activity without dismissing the window first. Your problem might be something similar to this?

Comment: Looking at the log and description, I wonder if the problem is related to hardware acceleration (there is some [description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)). Do you mind checking whether adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in your manifest makes any difference?

Comment: @Luke Taylor nothing related to AlertDialog..The issue is random..if i use application fast doing all operation i get into this state..@ Joe i Did try android:hardwareAccelerated = ture But no Use!!

Comment: To clarify, my suggestion is to add `hardwareAccelerated="false"`. Just in case you added "true" instead :)

Comment: @joe I never used hardwareAccelerated attribute..after u said i felt adding hardwareAccelerated="true" will Accelerate Hardware and somehow my issue will be solved...but no luck!!

Comment: NitZ, [the default is "true" if you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to "14"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#hwaccel) or higher, so you should try it with "false".

Comment: @Joe Till date i am not using target Attribute in Manifest..min is 8..But when i used  hardwareAccelerated="false" with target as 14.. Issue was seen frequently ;( ;( !!

Comment: I see, sorry it didn't help. The only other suggestion that I can think of is to check if you have any custom widget/views that implement its own `onDraw()` method and see if commenting out those will make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the Native Code(File Pointer Issue) in my project!!! But system is not able to throw the same error to ADB but instead it was throwing the above error!! pretty Strange though!!